# Thunderbird Ctrl+n for new message not working since I subscribed to news accounts

Tags: thunderbird, shortcuts

After subscribing to news accounts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> says something about a next new message instead of opening a new email. I could restore the functionality by removing the whole news account, but is there a way to fix this while keeping it?

Answer (score 0):

Which account have you set as default? Right click on an account name, choose *Settings* and at the bottom of the accounts list, there's a dropdown menu called *Account Actions*. Choose *Set as Default* for the appropriate account.